# Why is the matrix ($\frac{\partial \tilde x^j}{\partial x^i}$) invertible(Proposition 11.9 Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds)?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, co-tangent-space

In the following proof

[image]
[image]

**Why is the matrix ($\frac{\partial \tilde x^j}{\partial x^i}$) invertible?** I don't see any reason for that

As a side thing there seem to be a typo in the equation (which is not in the official errata of the book), I think it should be

$\Phi \circ \tilde \Phi^{-1}(p,( \xi_1,...,\xi_n))=...$

instead of

$\Phi \circ \tilde \Phi^{-1}(p,(\tilde \xi_1,...,\tilde\xi_n))=...$

because we are using the following equation:

[image]

Comment: By the chain rule, it's inverse is $(\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \tilde{x}^i})$. Equivalently, you can note that the transition map between the cotangent spaces is the transpose of the Jacobian of the transition map. Hence it's inverse is the transpose of the Jacobian of the inverse of the transition map, which is what is written in the first sentence of my comment.

Comment: @Kakashi Sorry, I don't see what chain rule are you refering to. Where is the composition that is being differentiated?

Comment: It's the general identity $DF(x)^{-1} = D(F^{-1})(F(x))$.

Comment: And you’re wrong about the suggested erratum. Perhaps it would help to look at the diagrams Lee surely has in the book. It is $\tilde\Phi{}^{-1}$ that  maps the $\tilde\xi$ coordinates back to the manifold.

Comment: @Kakashi. Are you saying that $\varphi= (x^1,...,x^n)$ and $\tilde \varphi =(\tilde x^1,..., \tilde x^n)$ are inverses of each other? Why would that be the case?, they are just two diffeomorphisms chosen independently of one another and they are functions of the points p of the manifold

Comment: with F=$\varphi$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ are a diffeomorphic function of the
coordinates $\tilde{x} = \left( \tilde{x}_1, \ldots, {\tilde{x}_n}  \right)$.
This is an abuse of notation, using $x$ to denote both points in $U$ and to
denote the transition diffemorphism $x : \tilde{U} \rightarrow U$, $x
(\tilde{x}) = x$. The inverse of this transition diffeomorphism is denoted
$\tilde{x}$. Differentiating the relation $\tilde{x}^i (x) = \tilde{x}^i$ with
respect to $\tilde{x}^j$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^i}{\partial x^k}  \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial
  \tilde{x}^j} & = & \delta_{i j} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $\left( \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^i}{\partial x^j} \right) = \left(
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \tilde{x}^j} \right)^{- 1}$. Hence $\left(
\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^i}{\partial x^j} \right)^T = \left( \frac{\partial
\tilde{x}^j}{\partial x^i} \right)$ is invertible.